# Proving $\phi (n_k) \ll \frac{n_k}{\log \log n_k}.$

Tags: number-theory

> Show that there is an increasing sequence of positive integers $n_1, n_2, \cdots$ such that $$\phi (n_k) \ll \frac{n_k}{\log \log n_k}.$$

I was able to prove that $\phi (n) \gg \frac{n}{\log \log n}$ (the proof is a bit lengthy, so I will not post it unless requested), but I am unsure how to show this result for an increasing sequence of positive integers.

Notation:

$f(x) \ll g(x)$ if $|f(x)|\leq Mg(x)$.

Comment: I thought $\psi(x) \sim x$, so you're giving an impossible task

Comment: If $\psi$ is Chebyshev's $\psi$, what mathworker21 said. If not, then what is $\psi$?

Comment: @mathworker21 and Daniel, I wrote psi instead of phi, for Euler's phi function. I apologize.

Comment: Then it totally makes sense. Do you know a nice product formula for $\phi(n)/n$?

Comment: @DanielFischer $\phi (n) / n = \prod_{p|n} (1 - 1/p)$.

Comment: Yes, and that says that $\phi(n)/n$ has new record lows at the primorials. Thus one should look at the primorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider numbers of the form $L_N = \prod_{p \le N} p$. Note $\log L_N = \psi(N) \sim N$, so $\log \log L_N \sim \log N$. And, $\phi(L_N) = \prod_{p \le N} (p-1)$, so you just need to show $\prod_{p \le N} (1-\frac{1}{p}) \ll \frac{1}{\log N}$. This is true.

Answer (score 0):

If $n_k=\prod\limits_{p\leq p_k}p$ (aka [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial#Definition_for_natural_numbers)) [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Computing_Euler's_totient_function) (also considering [Mertens' third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems#In_number_theory))
$$\frac{\phi(n_k)}{n_k}=
\prod\limits_{p\leq p_k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\sim 
\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln{p_k}}$$
This means that from some $k_0$ onwards
$$\frac{\phi(n_k)}{n_k}< (1+\varepsilon)
\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln{p_k}} \tag{1}$$
[But](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Asymptotics_and_bounds)
$$\ln{n_k}=\sum\limits_{p\leq p_k}\ln{p}=\vartheta(p_k) < 1.000028\cdot p_k$$
or
$$\ln{\ln(n_k)}-\ln{1.000028}<\ln{p_k}$$
and $(1)$ becomes
$$\frac{\phi(n_k)}{n_k}< (1+\varepsilon)
\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln{\ln(n_k)}-\ln{1.000028}}< (1+\varepsilon)^2
\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln{\ln(n_k)}} \tag{2}$$
simply because $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{1-\frac{\ln{1.000028}}{\ln{\ln(n_k)}}}=1$.

As a result for $(1+\varepsilon)^2 < e^{\gamma} \Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon: 0<\varepsilon <\sqrt{e^{\gamma}}-1 \approx 0.335, \exists k(\varepsilon)$ s.t.
$$\frac{\phi(n_k)}{n_k}< 
\frac{1}{\ln{\ln(n_k)}} \tag{3}$$
for $\forall k>k(\varepsilon)$.